# How can I install 0.12 version of a module if cpan has 0.13 version of module ?

Tags: cpan, perl-module

I want to install module `XML::XpathEngine` of version `0.12` . But `cpan` has `XML::XpathEngine` `0.13` version.

How can I install `XML::XpathEngine` `0.12` version ?

Comment: See related: [How can I install a specific version of a Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260593/how-can-i-install-a-specific-version-of-a-perl-module). Path to the 0.12 version of [XML::XpathEngine](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MI/MIROD/XML-XPathEngine-0.12.tar.gz).

Comment: used this command "install http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MI/MIROD/XML-XPathEngine-0.12.tar.gz" but not able to install. Is my command is correct

Comment: When I am installing giving error Writing Makefile for XML::XPathEngine
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to ask for it :

```
cpanm MIROD/XML-XPathEngine-0.12.tar.gz
```

It will install the version you need. To find the exact path to the version you want, go to the clan website, search for the version in the left side of the page and turn to this version. You should find the "download" link that can be truncated from the PAUSE is to the archive extension and used as a parameter with your favorite cpan client.