# How can I 'use' specific version of a perl CPAN module?

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module

I have a lot perl code that does different things in test and production, and I want to lock my code to specific versions of CPAN modules in case there are some changes to some of them in the future which may possibly break my code.

So I want to use specific versions of all the modules I use. By use I mean

```
use XML::Smart
```

Comment: Check whether this thread has any useful information for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260593/how-can-i-install-a-specific-version-of-a-perl-module

Comment: You are the exact use case for Pinto, by Jeffrey Thalhammer.  It's on CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Pinto

Comment: To elaborate: Pinto manages your dependency chain, allowing you to "pin" some modules at specific versions, while allowing others to upgrade as new releases come available.  You're able to roll back changes, and a lot more.  It's like version control geared specifically toward Perl modules/distributions.

Comment: Pinto doesn't mean that someone else ignores it and upgrades it through other means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use specific module refer [only](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/only-0.28/lib/only.pm)

```
use only MyModule => 0.30;
```

---

Also to print error if module version you want is above to currently installed one
You can say

```
use XML::Smart v1.6.9;
```

or

```
use XML::Smart 1.6.9;
```

or
for backward compatibility

```
use XML::Smart 1.006_009;
```

With reference from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) :

> - use Module VERSION LIST
> - use Module VERSION
> - use Module LIST
> - use Module
> - use VERSION
>
> If the VERSION argument is present between Module and LIST, then the
>   use will call the VERSION method in class Module with the given
>   version as an argument. The default VERSION method, inherited from the
>   UNIVERSAL class, croaks if the given version is larger than the value
>   of the variable $Module::VERSION .

Comment: That doesn't stop newer versions from being used.

Comment: @ikegami - sorry for that. Updated answer with [only](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/only-0.28/lib/only.pm) module

Answer (score 4):

You can do the low tech thing:

```
BEGIN {
    use XML::Simple;
    die "..." unless XML::Simple->VERSION eq '1.23';
    }
```

There is a headache knowing how a particular module reports its version. The `version` module is supposed to do version math, but I haven't found it reliable since there are too many ways to specify a version.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [`cpanfile`](https://metacpan.org/dist/Module-CPANfile/view/lib/cpanfile.pod) in your project root to declare dependencies on CPAN modules (you should), you can pin down the version there:

```perl
requires 'XML::Simple' => '== 1.23';
```