# How exactly to downgrade a Perl module version from latest one to older one?

Tags: perl, sockets, module, cpan

My problem is that i upgraded the version of the IO:Sockets:SSL to the latest one through cpan, but now one of my scripts doesnt work on this version of the module. I want to go back to version 1.4 (the latest is 2.027). So i found it and downloaded the .tar.gz file manually but i dont know what to do now.

I've never did this downgrade before and i found out that you cant do it through the cpan... so can someone explain me step by step what i should do ? I found a few answers to my question but i couldnt follow the steps correctly or most of them were unclear for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install a specific version of a set of Perl modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260593/how-can-i-install-a-specific-version-of-a-set-of-perl-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any dependencies which need to be downgraded you can run the following commands:

```
tar xvzf IO-Socket-SSL-1.40.tar.gz
cd IO-Socket-SSL-1.40
perl Makefile.PL
make test
make install   # If all the tests passed
```

But if your package has other dependencies which need to be downgraded, you will have to follow the same set of steps for those dependencies as well.

Comment: And do i have to delete some files from the version 2.027 when i'm going back to 1.4 ?

Comment: @user3242513, It'll overwrite most if not all of the files. Any extra files should be harmless.